# Disable scrolling on canvas while still allowing scrolling anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a canvas that sits within the body of an html page. If I don't disable scrolling on the canvas then I end up with 2 scrollbars (1 for the body and 1 for the canvas), with the canvas scrolling getting "stuck" for a few seconds. Needless to say the user experience isn't great.

So I disabled the scrolling in the canvas using the following:

```
$("my_canvas").bind("wheel mousewheel", function(e) {e.preventDefault()});
```

This works great, except the only way to scroll the page is to place the mouse on the very edge, outside the canvas area. The following image shows what I mean:

[image]

How can I disable the scrolling on the canvas (to prevent the 2 scrollbars) but still allow the body to scroll regardless of mouse position?

Comment: Have you tried using css? Using `overflow: hidden;` on the canvas element should work. Or I believe you can do it in jQuery by `$('my_canvas').css("overflow", "hidden")` but I haven't tested it.

Comment: hmm thought I tried that but it seems to be working now. I made the html and body have  overflow:scroll !important; and the canvas  overflow: hidden !important;  Thank you!